# "Environment Variables" view for jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

For freestyle job I used to have "environment variable" view that allowed me to view all the variables that were available during runtime of the build.

What is the equivalent for pipeline job?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your pipeline to view variables at runtime

- For linux

  ```
   sh 'env > env.txt'
   for (String i : readFile('env.txt').split("\r?\n")) {
       println i
   }
  ```
- For windows

  ```
  bat 'set > env.txt' 
  for (String i : readFile('env.txt').split("\r?\n")) {
      println i
  }
  ```

Comment: it's a nice solution +1, but it's not what I was looking for. I was looking for an actual view that users find usually on the side panel

Answer (score 0):

I also was surprised there's no Environment variables view.  Anyhow this is simpler than a loop:

```
    stage("Env Variables") {
        steps {
            sh "printenv"
        }
    }
```

Or in simple scripting syntax, with sorted output:

```
    stage('env') {
         sh 'printenv|sort'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 sh "env | sort"
```